# "Freeze" (GitLab) old origin while migrating to new origin

Tags: gitlab

We have migrated to *Github* from *Gitlab*. I'd like to keep the Gitlab repos (for a while), and in the meantime I'd like to cause error on client git push/pull requests to remind devs to change their remote to the new origin.

Does anyone have any tactics for this?

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted gitlab, or you were hosting your repositories on gitlab.com? In the former case, just disabling your gitlab server (or restricting access to `localhost` or something) seems like it would accomplish what you want.

Comment: @larsks Yep, it is self hosted. Its a good idea, but there is one or two repos that I don't have control over that are still on Gitlab.

Comment: Does gitlab provide per-repository access controls that you could use to simply revoke all access to the repositories you wish to block?